# SEO is not working on pages

Tags: seo

I downloaded Yoast SEO plugin and also followed the rules to show page on google. But my pages are been not shown on google rather content are visible like uploaded pdf n images. The only thing is not showing is pages. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Installing a plugin isn't going to "solve" SEO problems. You should probably read [The beginners guide to SEO](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo). [SEO Starter Guide](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) and [6 things about SEO you should know](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/fact-or-fiction-6-things-about-seo-that-you-should-probably-be-aware-of) just to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Greg McMullen, this isn't an issue with WordPress but with your site being listed on Google.  You need to submit your site to Google to crawl, through the Webmaster Tools ... this also isn't something that happens immediately it will take some time.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

I also don't recommend Yoast SEO, being a full time WordPress developer I have tried all of them, and this is by far the best one available right now:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/autodescription/

Very simple and clean interface, without bloat, and makes it very easy for beginners to setup and get up and running very quick.